# Created PDF's in a drop down menu

Tags: sql, reporting-services

Currently we use SQL Server Reporting services for reporting. We have 2 PDF's that were created that have data in them. Is it at all possible to insert them into either report builder or to be able to filter these two by having a drop down menu?

For Example:

I have Fiscal Year 19 4th Quarter.pdf file now I have a Fiscal Year 20 1st Quarter.pdf file. Is it possible to make there be a drop down where if I selected Fiscal year 19 it would bring up that pdf and or vice versa?

I don't think that it is possible since they are pdf's but thought I would check.

[Example image of pdf files in SSRS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VRj0D.png)

Comment: Not sure if you can use a dropdown, but you could probably use the [Go To Url](https://www.tutorialgateway.org/go-to-url-action-in-ssrs/) action on a textbox to link to the .pdf on your report server.

Comment: alternative is to get a list of pdf files in your folder into ssrs and use them as drop down parameters. Then based on selection.. simply build an URL pointing to the same selected PDF.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a parameter to your report, where you can select the year and the quarter.
It's incredibly stupid to have to make a new report for every year.

If you need a SQL for the quarters, 10 years back, 10 years ahead, this will do:

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(year,  DATEDIFF(year, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -10, 0)  AS quarter_begin   
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(month, 3, CTE.quarter_begin) AS quarter_begin 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE YEAR(DATEADD(month, 3, CTE.quarter_begin))  < YEAR(DATEADD(year,  DATEDIFF(year, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) +11, 0) ) 
)
SELECT * FROM CTE
```

Or more elaborate

```
;WITH CTE AS 
(
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(year,  DATEDIFF(year, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) -10, 0)  AS quarter_begin   
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT 
        DATEADD(month, 3, CTE.quarter_begin) AS quarter_begin 
    FROM CTE 
    WHERE YEAR(DATEADD(month, 3, CTE.quarter_begin))  < YEAR(DATEADD(year,  DATEDIFF(year, 0, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) +11, 0) ) 
)
,CTE2 AS 
(
    SELECT 
         quarter_begin
        ,DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month, 3, CTE.quarter_begin)) AS quarter_end 
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY YEAR(quarter_begin) ORDER BY quarter_begin) AS quarter_no 
        ,YEAR(quarter_begin) AS quarter_year 
    FROM CTE 
)
SELECT 
     quarter_begin
    ,quarter_end
    ,N'Q' + CAST(quarter_no AS nvarchar(4)) + '-' + CAST(quarter_year AS nvarchar(4)) AS txt  
FROM CTE2 

ORDER BY quarter_begin
```